# aggregate and distinct linq query output to list

Tags: c#, linq

How can I transform linq query output using aggregate operators and display distinct outputs to a list?

Here is what I have stored in DB, which is being pulled via linq query:

```
   Date        Hours
07/29/2013      1.3
07/29/2013      2.0
07/30/2013      3.1
07/31/2013      0.1
07/31/2013      5.2
08/01/2013      1.1
08/01/2013      1.1
08/01/2013      2.2
08/02/2013      3.3
08/02/2013      4.0
08/03/2013      2.1
```

Here is how I want the data:

```
   Day          Hours
07/29/2013       3.3
07/30/2013       3.1
07/31/2013       5.3
08/01/2013       4.4
08/02/2013       7.3
08/03/2013       2.1
```

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: I think `07/29/2013 ->  3.3`, `08/02/2013 -> 7.3`,... what is the actual rule? (I guess the rule is the sum of hours on each group).

Comment: @KingKing Correct, its just a sum. I have updated above

Answer (score 7):

Use `GroupBy` and `Sum`:

```
var result = db.Table
    .GroupBy(r => r.Date)
    .Select(g => new{ Day=g.Key, Hours=g.Sum(r=> r.Hours) })
```

If `Date` is actually a `DateTime` you should use `r.Date.Date` to remove the time portion.

Comment: You should replace `Date=` with `Day=`

Comment: You beat me, I was about to post my answer which is exactly same as yours which doesn't makes sense. so +1.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Why is my query not working!? I added a Where Clause to filter for the correct results, but its not working

var result = db.Table.Where(r => r.Date >= week)
               .GroupBy(r => r.DateWorked)
               .Select(g => new { Day = g.Key, Hours = g.Sum(r => r.Hours) });

Comment: @user793468: Maybe because `DateWorked` is a `DateTime` with a time portion. Then have a look at the last sentence in my answer. If that doesn't help you need to specify "not working".

Comment: @TimSchmelter yes, it is date time. but I get this error when I try ".Date"
'System.Nullable<System.DateTime>' does not contain a definition for 'Date' and no extension method 'Date' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Nullable<System.DateTime>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @TimSchmelter I tried this and it still wont display results:
 'r.Date.Value.Date.ToString()' 
Once I remove the "GroupBy" and "Select" and Add "OrderBy" i see the results, is there something wrong with the "GroupBy--Select" part?

Comment: Then it is a Nullable<DateTime>. You have to check if it has a value, then you can access the Value property to get the DateTime

Comment: @TimSchmelter Why do we have to check if it has a value or not? If I hover over the result variable it does show results. The only difference is "GroupBy--Select" and "OrderBy" linq queries show results in different formats: Hourss = {System.Data.Linq.DataQuery<<>f__AnonymousType5<string,decimal?>>} and  Hours = {SELECT [t0].[Description], [t0].[Code], [t0].[Hours], [t0].[Date] FROM [vwHours] AS [t0]
WHERE ([... respectively